# "Distribute your app on Android Wear" is disabled

Tags: android

In my Android play console "Distribute your app on Android Wear" is disabled.

I added 2 screenshot images and 3 apk files:
1 app
1 wear 1
1 wear 2

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    publishNonDefault true

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        wear1 {
            versionCode 17
            versionName "17.0"
        }
        wear2 {
            versionCode 18
            versionName "18.0"
            minSdkVersion 25
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.1'
    provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.1'
}
```

This is the wearable manifest file:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
<application ...>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
        android:value="true" />
    ...
</application>
```

and this is the mobile gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.0.1'
    ...
    wearApp project(path:':Wearable', configuration: "wear1Release")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

Why is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

You version code of mobile app must match version code of wearable wear1 product flavor.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I insert 2 apk with the same code?
The second overrides the first